# Keras LSTM is not learning

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I'm trying to understand how Keras' LSTM model works so I took an Udemy course and the teacher built a model with an LSTM to predict Google stock prices. The model works really well and here it is:

```
# Part 1 - Data Preprocessing
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the training set
training_set = pd.read_csv('Google_Stock_Price_Train.csv')
training_set = training_set.iloc[:,1:2].values

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
sc = MinMaxScaler()
training_set = sc.fit_transform(training_set)

# Getting the inputs and the ouputs
X_train = training_set[0:1257]
y_train = training_set[1:1258]

# Reshaping
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (1257, 1, 1))

# Part 2 - Building the RNN

# Importing the Keras libraries and packages
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM

# Initialising the RNN
regressor = Sequential()

# Adding the input layer and the LSTM layer
regressor.add(LSTM(units=4, activation = 'sigmoid', input_shape = (None, 1)))

# Adding the output layer
regressor.add(Dense(units = 1))

# Compiling the RNN
regressor.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')

# Fitting the RNN to the Training set
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 32, epochs = 200)

# Part 3 - Making the predictions and visualising the results

# Getting the real stock price of 2017
test_set = pd.read_csv('Google_Stock_Price_Test.csv')
real_stock_price = test_set.iloc[:,1:2].values

# Getting the predicted stock price of 2017
inputs = real_stock_price
inputs = sc.transform(inputs)
inputs = np.reshape(inputs, (20, 1, 1))
predicted_stock_price = regressor.predict(inputs)
predicted_stock_price = sc.inverse_transform(predicted_stock_price)

# Visualising the results
plt.plot(real_stock_price, color = 'red', label = 'Real Google Stock Price')
plt.plot(predicted_stock_price, color = 'blue', label = 'Predicted Google Stock Price')
plt.title('Google Stock Price Prediction')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Google Stock Price')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Now I want to apply my own data to this model to predict the next product that a person might purchase using their purchased history. The only thing I changed in this model is the input data:

Original stock price data is the open price of stock day by day:

> 720, 800, 520, ... etc (one column, one feature)

My data is in the same format, which is the IDs of a product that a user purchased:

> 15, 1320, 680, ... etc (one column, one feature)

The problem is the model is not learning my data, the loss value does not change. I want to know if there is a problem with my data or if the model is not well adapted to my problem?

Please help and sorry about my english. :)

------------------------ Update ----------------------
a few epochs of training:

Epoch 1/200
12507/12507 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.1870
Epoch 2/200
12507/12507 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 0.0705
Epoch 3/200
12507/12507 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 0.0699
Epoch 4/200
12507/12507 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 0.0699
Epoch 5/200
12507/12507 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 0.0699
Epoch 6/200
12507/12507 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 0.0699
Epoch 7/200
12507/12507 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 0.0699
Epoch 8/200
12507/12507 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 0.0699
Epoch 9/200
12507/12507 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 0.0699

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you think ID is a good representation of a product? What if flat screen tv is 200 and soap is 201? Doesn't seem a good way to represent the data...

Comment: ohm, so you think that my data has a problem? i think that if the model can't predict the next product, at least it can product the next number in the sequence? i'm trying to under stand the model :(

Comment: Can you add a few epochs of the loss to your question?

Comment: yes! i also train the model without normalize the input (feature scaling part - keep the original input number) and the loss change is very slow!

Comment: Please try to plot both the dataset and see the variation. It will surely help you building LSTM model accordingly. I have been through such scenario and sometimes it take more layer to fit the dataset.

Comment: Which udemy class did you take if I may ask?